# Why int16+int16 is faster than int16+int8?

Tags: c

I decided to make a benchmark to test how fast each C99 type is, out of curiosity.

My benchmark creates a array of the following struct:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    short spdx;
    short spdy;
    unsigned char type;
} defaultTypes;
```

Then I do this operation on the entire struct, multiple times, to simulate a game update loop:

```
while(counter < ARRAY_MAX)
{
    fastStruct[counter].x+=fastStruct[counter].spdx;
    fastStruct[counter].y+=fastStruct[counter].spdy;
    ++counter;
}
```

I tried several types, like int_fast8_t and double.

Later I decided to test what if I made the "spdx" variable bigger too? So I made a version where both the position (x, y) and the speed (spdx, spdy) variables are int16_t

To my surprise, it is SLIGHLY, but only SLIGHLY faster than the int16_t + int8_t version, it was 11% faster to be more exact (compared for example to doubles, that run a quarter of the int16_t+int16_t version speed).

For most other speed differences (floats being slower, bigger variables being slower, and so on) I think I know the reasons, but I don't know why a bigger structure (16, 16, 16, 16, 8) is FASTER than a smaller one (even with padding, 16, 16, 8, 8, 8).

Thus, why doing int16_t+=int16_t is 11% faster than int16_t+=int8_t? Someone suggested it had to do with integer promotion, but I am not sure about that.

Important note (seemly this affect the results): I compiled this with MingW, targeting 32-bit, and running on a 64-bit bit x86 (I ran only once a test targeting 64-bit, thus I am not confident of its results, but the performance gap is seemly 2% instead of 11%)

Comment: Can you do a diff of the generated code (i.e. assembly) ?

Comment: Any recommended tool to try that?

Comment: Uh, you can get `gcc` to output assembly using -S. You can also use `objdump` to disassemble an elf.

Comment: I'm guessing alignment. I have absolutely no proof, nor the will to write a benchmark to try and prove it :-). Drop the struct, and operate on a vector or array to see if it happens there too. Also, you are using optimizations when comparing, right?

Comment: the -S output is this... http://pastebin.com/c6n4vGrb it has all different structures tested on it

Comment: I have to go now (unexpected thing in real life here), later I might return and peruse the ASM and see if I can paste only the sum part or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer has to do with the fact that your variables are signed.  For two (signed) variables with the same type, the cpu can add them using a native instruction.  However, when the types are different, even just different sizes, it has to convert one to the other.  This may or may not be supported in hardware, but it is still a necessary step.  Consider if your int16 was 256 and your int8 was -1. You would expect to get back an int16 value of 257.  If the CPU just added the bit patterns together, then you'd get something very different, because the 8bit representation of -1 is not the same as the 16bit representation of -1. First it has to convert the 8-bit number to a 16 bit number, then add them together.

This is what is meant by "integer promotion": the compiler recognizes that the vars are of different types, and uses the appropriate assembly code to do the conversion.  It "promotes" the int8 to an int16 before doing the add operation.

I'll bet if you changed them to unsigned, the difference in speed would disappear.